# Performance evaluation of Transparent Huge Pages (THP) of Linux

Tags: mongodb, linux-kernel, redis

Could you tell me real application examples which show performance degradation caused by Transparent Huge Pages (THP) of Linux?
Some home pages tell that DB applications (Hadoop, mongoDB, redis, etc.) show performance degradation, but I cannot confirm the results.

I want to evaluate the performance with THP or without THP.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For redis the performance degradation is well documented and tested, and it's recommended to disable hugepages, from redis' TFM:

> Unfortunately when a Linux kernel has transparent huge pages enabled,
>   Redis incurs to a big latency penalty after the fork call is used in
>   order to persist on disk. Huge pages are the cause of the following
>   issue: Fork is called, two processes with shared huge pages are
>   created. In a busy instance, a few event loops runs will cause
>   commands to target a few thousand of pages, causing the copy on write
>   of almost the whole process memory. This will result in big latency
>   and big memory usage.

See:

http://antirez.com/news/84

http://redis.io/topics/latency

Answer (score 0):

When the application data being accessed is contiguous, THP often boosts performance, but if the memory access patterns are not contiguous, THP may cause system instability.

Database workloads often have sparse rather than contiguous memory access, so THP can cause performance degradation.

If your database gets high `sys cpu`, high `sys load` or abnormal RES usage, it might be related to THP.

reference: [Why We Disable Linux's THP Feature for Databases](https://pingcap.com/blog/why-we-disable-linux-thp-feature-for-databases/)